# "RuntimeError: No application found." when doing unit testing in Python with Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I just started to work on python application that use Flask and SQL Alchemy. I have to do the unit tests of all the routes (no unit test had been done yet) but I have a problem when I try to run the test :

the route :

```
class AuthResetPassword(Resource):
@cross_origin()
def post(self):
    try:
        body = request.get_json()
        email = body.get('email')
        token = body.get('token')
        password = body.get('password')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if token != user.token:
            return flask.make_response(flask.jsonify(success=False, error={"code": 115, "message": "Token incorrect"}), 403)

        hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt())
        user.password = hashed.decode("utf-8")
        db.session.commit()
        send_email('Password Reset',
                   sender='derush.app@gmail.com',
                   recipients=[user.email],
                   text_body='Your password was succesfully reset.',
                   html_body='<p>Your password was succesfully reset.</p>')
        return flask.make_response(flask.jsonify(success=True), 200)
    except Exception as e:
        raise InternalServerError
```

the test :

```
class TestAuthResource(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch("pomelo_backend.user.User.query.filter_by")
    @mock.patch("pomelo_backend.api_base.db.session.commit")
    @mock.patch("pomelo_backend.resources.AuthResource.send_email")
    def test_post(self, mock_select_user, mock_db_commit, mock_send_email):
        user_correct_token = json.dumps({"email": "user@user.com", "token": "correctToken", "password": "password"})
        user_wrong_token = json.dumps({"email": "user@user.com", "token": "wrongToken", "password": "password"})

        correct_token_response = json.dumps({"success": True})
        wrong_token_user = json.dumps({"success": False, "error": {"code": 115, "message": "Token incorrect"}})

        mock_select_user.return_value(user_correct_token)
        mock_db_commit.return_value(True)
        mock_send_email.return_value(True)

        response_user_correct_token = AuthResetPassword.post(user_correct_token)
        response_user_wrong_token = AuthResetPassword.post(user_wrong_token)

        self.assertEqual(response_user_correct_token, correct_token_response)
        self.assertEqual(response_user_wrong_token, wrong_token_user)
```

But it returns : "RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context."
I tried to instantiate the app with this but it doesn't work :

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

I don't find template or tutorial online that helps, most of the time it's too simplistic.
Thanks!

Comment: did you set the app using `FLASK_APP=appname`, https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/

Comment: Yes and it didn't change anything, always the same error. I tried with the method shown here : https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/pytest-mocking-cheatsheet-dcebd84876e3 , but it doesn't work.